# Datagridview gender value to combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want datagridview value to appear on 'new entry forms' (textboxes but also combobox) when I click on it.

This is my code which works but only for textboxes because i **don't know how to get GENDER value 'out from' datagridview back to combobox**.

My combobox values are "M" and "F" and i know how to enter them into datagridview but the other way round is problem.

```
private void dataGridViewKontakti_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        lblID.Visible = true;
        lblIDPromjena.Visible = true;

        int i;
        i = dataGridViewKontakti.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

        lblIDPromjena.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBoxIme.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBoxPrezime.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        textBoxZvanje.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        textBoxZanimanje.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        textBoxTelefon.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        textBoxAdresa.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        textBoxPost.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        textBoxGrad.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        textBoxEmail.Text = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
```

You'l see the empty space between cells 4 and 6. Cell 5 is my GENDER cell.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are doing/asking here.  If you are pulling a value from a DataGridView, please show us what value you are expecting, what value you are receiving, and if you get an exception, where that is happening

Comment: I am registering new user with his Name, Surname, Title, Job, GENDER (with combobox values M or F), telephone, adress, post office, city and e-mail.

The thing I need to do is get values from datagridview appear back in my textboxes (but also in combobox) when I click on one row in it.

The code i wrote gets values "back" into textboxes, but I also need my GENDER value (M or F) to appear on my combobox when I click on one row (and I don't know how to do that)

Comment: In order for values to show in a combobox, you need to have a list of items in that combobox.  Where is your code where you create the combobox?  Did you set the value/display member?  In your code you never access value 5?  Did you even try it to see what happens?  Can you show us what happens??  I cannot help you unless you show us more code for your application

Comment: //added 2 items in my combobox

cbSpol.Items.Add("M");
cbSpol.Items.Add("F");

//Conversion into string

private void cbSpol_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Convert.ToString(cbSpol.SelectedItem);
        }

//INSERT string with kSpol for entering GENDER from combobox.

String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.kontakti (kIme, kPrezime, kSpol, kTelefon, kAdresa, kPost, kGrad, kEmail) VALUES (kIme, kPrezime, kZvanje, kZanimanje, kSpol, ....");

...
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("kSpol", cbSpol.SelectedItem);
...

(with @ beside parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think you would need to set the SelectedItem on the ComboBox assuming your data has a string "M" and "F" in it:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("M");
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("F");

        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "M";

    }
```

Comment: yes but I've already set the values with this
<pre>
cbSpol.Items.Add("M");
cbSpol.Items.Add("F");
<code>

I didn't write the public form() and so because I'm losing comment space.

I need something like this:

<pre>
cbSpol.SelectedItem = dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
<code>

This is the line that I need but it doesn't work and I want to know why ? I wrote it from the head and I know this doesn't work.

When I click on (for example) 3rd row in datagrid I get all the values BACK TO TEXTBOXES but combobox doesn't recieve the value from datagrid (it remains blank)

Comment: What is the value of this line `dataGridViewKontakti.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value`

Comment: I just tried to change cbSpol.SelectedItem INTO cbSpolText and it works .... the datagridview returns its gender value BACK TO GENDER COMBOBOX and it works now !

But I still don't get why does not combobox need SelectedItem instead of .Text

Anyway ... it is fixed now. @Matthew THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Im new user so I cannot give you positive grade but if I'd could i would have done it immidiately.

Thank you again for your trouble !